# Need to figure out the error with the return statement in the determineAsst module

Tags: java

I am trying to get this code to work and my problem lies in getting the return statement correct so it will print the correct results. Any help is greatly appreciated. The problem lies in getting it to return the correct value. When I did have it working it would return a value of 0.

```
public static void main (String []args){

    int famIncome, numChildren, asstTotal, asstAmount;

    numChildren = userChildren();

    famIncome = userIncome();

    asstTotal = determineAsst(numChildren, famIncome);

    System.out.println(asstTotal);
    }

public static int userChildren (){
    int children = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Your Number of Children: ");
    children = keyboard.nextInt();

    return children;
}

public static int userIncome (){
    int income = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Your Family Income: ");
    income = keyboard.nextInt();

    return income;
}

public static void displayResults(int famIncome, int numChildren){

    System.out.println("Your Income is: " + famIncome + " " + "Children: " + numChildren);

}

public static int determineAsst (int userIncome, int numChildren){


    if(userIncome > 25000 && numChildren > 2){
        int asstTotal = 0;

         asstTotal = numChildren * 1000;

         return asstTotal;

    }


    return asstTotal;


}
```

}

Comment: this will not compile (take a look at `public static int determineAsst`), why don't you make it compile first. Maybe by doing that you will fix your problem ;)

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (conditional, statement, return, value) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 1):

In order to compile, this

```
public static int determineAsst (int userIncome, int numChildren){
   if(userIncome > 25000 && numChildren > 2){
      int asstTotal = 0;
      asstTotal = numChildren * 1000;
      return asstTotal;
   }
   return asstTotal;
}
```

must be changed to this:

```
public static int determineAsst (int userIncome, int numChildren){
   int asstTotal = 0;
   if(userIncome > 25000 && numChildren > 2){
      asstTotal = numChildren * 1000;
   }
   return asstTotal;
}
```

In your original code, the `asstTotal` variable is not declared until inside the if block. This means that once the if block exits, that variable no longer exists. It's in the wrong [scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html), and therefore, the return statement will not compile.

Also, as mentioned by @donfuxx, the return statement inside the if-block is unnecessary. It works, but it's redundant.

Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

rewrite method like this:

```
public static int determineAsst (int userIncome, int numChildren){

    int asstTotal = 0; //here!
    if(userIncome > 25000 && numChildren > 2){
        //int asstTotal = 0; not here!

         asstTotal = numChildren * 1000;

         //return statement here not necessary 

    }


    return asstTotal;


}
```